# Sistema de notificações para multipla ação e conteúdo

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Estou tentando compreender a melhor forma de fazer um esquema de notificações para múltiplas ações e nodes. Basicamente deve-se notificar alguém sempre que uma ação do tipo *mensagem* ou *curtir* for realizada.

<sub>Mensagem: `Fulano de tal enviou uma mensagem`</sub>

<sub>Curtiu: `Fulano de tal curtiu seu texto [prévia com texto]`</sub>

---

O problema etá em relacionar tudo isso, pois um caso preciso do nome do usuário e em outro caso relacionar para recuperar o texto e o link.

```
select
case tipo
    when 'mensagem' then ( [...] )
    when 'curtiu'   then ( select concat( nome , '//' , acao , '//' , body ) from tabela
                           inner join [...] where [...] )
end `data`
from notificacao
```

Como é linha-linha, pensei em fazer um select simples com subquery em cada caso dependendo do tipo da notificação, usar `concat` e `explode` para partir os elementos. A query acima retornaria linhas como `Papa Cahrlie//curtiu//Lorem ipsum...`.

Nesse esquema cada tipo teria uma subquery, mas tenho mais 'eventos' alem do exemplo, e terei querys mais complexas. Poderia ate recorrer às `views` se for o caso.

---

<sub>TABELA:</sub>

```
CREATE TABLE `notificacao` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USUARIO` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTEUDO` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIPO` enum( '...' ),
  `STATUS` enum( '0' , '1' ) DEFAULT '0',
)
```

Minha tabela é simples - genérica - , que grava o usuário, o tipo de evento e a referência do conteúdo que sofreu a ação. Queria opiniões sobre trabalhar esse select de forma mais simples e/ou eficiente.

Answer (score 2):

Eu sugiro que você crie uma tabela-mestra de notificações e duas tabelas-filhas; uma para as notificações de mensagem e outra para as notificações de curtida:

```
CREATE TABLE notificacao (
    notificacao_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    lida BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
    data_criacao DATETIME NOT NULL,
    -- outros campos, e.g. data/hora que a notificação foi lida…
    -- você pode também desnormalizar o banco de dados e colocar aqui o id do usuário
    PRIMARY KEY (notificao_id));

CREATE TABLE notificacao_mensagem (
    notificacao_id INT NOT NULL,
    mensagem_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (notificacao_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (notificacao_id) REFERENCES notificacao,
    FOREIGN KEY (mensagem_id) REFERENCES mensagem (id));

CREATE TABLE notificacao_curtida (
    notificacao_id INT NOT NULL,
    curtida_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (curtida_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (notificacao_id) REFERENCES notificacao,
    FOREIGN KEY (curtida_id) REFERENCES curtida (id));
```

Na hora que você precisar saber quem curtiu quem, você faz o join apropriado. Se você precisar puxar tudo em uma tabela só depois, você pode compor uma view usando LEFT OUTER JOINs:

```
CREATE VIEW notificacao AS
SELECT
    …
FROM
    notificacao
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        notificacao_mensagem
        INNER JOIN mensagem ON …condição…) USING (notificacao_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        notificacao_curtida
        INNER JOIN curtida ON …condição…) USING (notificacao_id)
    …outras notificações…
```

Você diferenciaria os tipos de notificação pela presença de NULLs — só as curtidas teriam `notificao_curtida.curtida_id IS NOT NULL`, por exemplo.

Comment: Agradeço, mas como disse na questão, para cada ação há um relacionamento diferente. A 'curtida' se relaciona com o texto para mostrar uma prévia, e mensagens só preciso do autor. Talvez o uso de `UNION ALL` possa substituir o `CASE`, mas não resolve os relacionamentos.

Comment: Não entendi o problema dos relacionamentos; a ideia de separar as notificações em tabelas é exatamente para permitir o JOIN das notificações de mensagens com as tabelas de mensagens e o JOIN das notificações de curtidas com as tabelas de curtidas. O que você tem em mente que seria impossível fazendo o esquema desse jeito?

Comment: Mensagem só precisa notificar que X mandou mensagem para Y; Curtida relaciona para X que Y curtiu o texto *Lorem ipsum...*; `UNION ALL` não vai funcionar pois são relacionamentos para campos diferentes.

Comment: Se as notificações são heterogêneas demais pra habitarem uma tabela só, você tem que fazer duas consultas: uma para as curtidas, outra para as mensagens — a solução com CONCAT/EXPLODE só funciona até alguém colocar na sua base de dados alguma string com o delimitador que você escolheu (acidentalmente ou maliciosamente), e aí o seu PHP vai quebrar os campos todos errados… Você pode implementar um sistema de escaping, mas aí toda hora que você botar ou tirar algo do banco de dados você vai precisar fazer e desfazer o escaping.

Comment: Pois é, ja me passou pela cabeça esse inconveniente. Fazer 2 consulta distintas será um problema ordenar pela data.

Comment: Eu editei a minha resposta para ela se tornar uma solução com LEFT OUTER JOINs — você vai receber uma tabela entupida de NULLs, mas você vai poder ter colunas distintas para notificações distintas, *e* ordenar pela data.